# Any way to make weather widget stick to its place?

Tags: macos, dashboard-widget

I have four weather widgets on my dashboard at the moment. The problem I'm finding is that when I arrange them one way - every now and then some of them move down by 20-100 px approximately.

I think it has to do with the weather graphic that is being loaded (i.e. sun, snow, rain, etc.). Sometimes they're taller than expected by the widget and it repositions itself which messes with my arrangement.

## Question

Is there a way to make weather widgets stick to the place I position it at?
Does anybody know how to stop the rearrangement of the weather widgets?

#### Arranged:

[image]

#### Displaced:

[image]

Comment: This has been bugging me for nearly *eight years*, ever since Dashboard was first introduced. I'm amazed it still hasn't been fixed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason the weather widgets jump around is because the icon pictures of the current weather stick out above the widget itself. For example, the clouds or rain images. When the weather changes, the images change, and since they stick out different amounts, they move around to accommodate the change.

This is fixable but results in a tiny bit of chopping-off of the top of the widget image. Worth it in my opinion, you can hardly notice the chop-off.

Edit the file:

```
/Library/Widgets/Weather.wdgt/Weather.js
```

On line 359, change:

```
maxOffset = entry.voffset > maxOffset ? entry.voffset : maxOffset;
```

To:

```
maxOffset = 0;
```

It may be a different line number - 359 is correct for Snow Leopard. You should search the file for the correct one.

You need to redo this when you update OSX.

Comment: This might just work. Testing. Thanks for the tip @Mark

Comment: Edited my answer with more explanation

Comment: Sadly, this doesn't work for me on my Air running Mountain Lion as I switch from clamshell mode to display and back occasionally. This change also clips off the top of the drawing so sunshine or snow or clouds have a hard top edge which looks poor compared to the stock widget that fades out by being drawn completely rather than being cropped with a hard edge.

Answer (score 2):

I know this isn't a very technical solution. Place the weather widgets side by side at the bottom of the screen, so when an image changes it doesn't bump into another widget.